# Setting what table a DbContext maps to

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In an application I'm working on, I have what are essentially a bunch of lookup tables in a database which all contain two things: The `ID` (int) and a `Value` (string).

There's only a handful of them, but I want to map all of them to a single `Context` which depends on the table name. Something like:

```
class LookupContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Lookup> Lookups { get; set; }

    public LookupContext(String table)
    {
        // Pseudo code:
        // Bind Lookups based on what table is
        Lookups = MyDatabase.BindTo(table);
    }
}
```

So if I create a `new LookupContext("foo")`, it binds against the foo table. If I do `new LookupContext("bar")` it uses the bar table, and so forth.

Is there any way to do this? Or do I have to create a separate context + model for every table I have?

This is more or less my first time doing this, so I'm not really sure if what I'm doing is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer we ***should*** be able to give you is to use enums, but that's not available quite yet - it's in the next version of EF.  See here for details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/walkthrough-enums-june-ctp.aspx

With earlier versions of EF, you can simply create a class per lookup value (assuming state as an example) and have code that looks something like the following:

```
public class State
{
  public int StateId {get;set;}
  public string StateName {get;set;}
}

public class LookupContext : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<State> States {get;set;}
  // ... more lookups as DbSets
}
```

This will allow you to use one context but will still require one class per table.  You can also use the fluent API if you want your table/column names to differ from your class/property names respectively.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I actually realized I was completely over complicating things beyond reason. There was no reason for storing multiple tables with two columns.

I'm better off storing my data as:

```
public class LookupValue
{
    public string LookupValueId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string LookupType { get; set; }
}
```

Where the third field was simply the name of the table that I was previously storing in the database.

I'm still interested in the idea of mapping a single `Context` class to multiple tables, but I believe what I described above is the least convoluted way of accomplishing what I need.